# How can I fill the full width and height of GridView by cells using android:stretchMode="columnWidth"?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, gridview, layout

I want to create grid cells with different (but similar) width and height, so they cover the full available area of the parent view. For example:

```
parent width is 33
grid cells: width 10, width 10, width 13
```

Here what I'm currently getting and the code:

[image]

XML code of the `GridView`:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    style="?styleCaldroidGridView" />
```

Even `android:gravity="center"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` don't work as workaround.

P.S. I'm trying to fix this issue in `Caldroid` calendar.

Comment: set the property of the grid ColumnWidth to "*"

Comment: @Dmitry I think you need to think differently, to make your view responsive to different sizes. So, decide the number of columns and raws, then give each the same weight (1), on both directions. Let the parent view to match_parent on both sides, and let the outer view to decide the size (here you can test different sizes). Last but not least, center each number-view within its cell.

Comment: @Alessio But I'm inflating `GridView` will the same cells. I can't make the outer cell to be different in code.

Comment: @Vishal Thakkar I can't find any property similar to `ColumnWidth`.

Comment: @Dmitry you had edit post when you had post for gridView  this property you get in gridView

Comment: @Dmitry that's why I chose not to use GridView at all. I instead use GridLayout: my responsive class extends GridLayout, and I inflate an xml GridLayout to it. Each item / cell has its own size in my case, and the outer parent (my GridLayout) can shrink and expand as much as it wants, all the items are centered and keep centered and the view is fully responsive. This was the best way for me to go. Please consider to do the same.

Comment: @Vishal Thakkar You're right. I hope, I finally posted the correct code this time. But `android:columnWidth="*"` leads to the error: `error: '*' is incompatible with attribute android:columnWidth (attr) dimension.`

Comment: @Alessio Thanks for your advise. But it can be hard to rewrite the code of a third-party library. I'm trying to fix this issue in `Caldroid` calendar.

Comment: https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/issues/160

Comment: @Vishal Thakkar They're writing about another issue where they get half of the screen of the empty space. I'm already using normal TextView and fixed that another issue. It doesn't help with the issue in this topic. Thanks anyway.